# Python list to tuple

Tags: python, arrays

I have this :

```
(([75, 0], [100, 0], [100, 370]), ([75, 0], [100, 370], [75, 370]))
```

that come from this :

```
 [(array([75,  0]), array([100,   0]), array([100, 370])), (array([75,  0]), array([100, 370]), array([ 75, 370]))]
```

and I want to have :

```
[(x1, y1, x2 , y2 ,x3 ,y3), (x1, y1, x2 , y2 ,x3 ,y3), ...]
```

or

```
[(75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370), (75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370),.....]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what pyton data type is `array([75,  0]), array([100,   0]),..`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.chain`:

```
import itertools
s = (([75, 0], [100, 0], [100, 370]), ([75, 0], [100, 370], [75, 370])) 
final_s = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(i)) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370], [75, 0, 100, 370, 75, 370]]
```

or using `reduce` in Python2:

```
s = (([75, 0], [100, 0], [100, 370]), ([75, 0], [100, 370], [75, 370]))    
new_s = [reduce(lambda x, y:list(x)+list(y), i) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[[75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370], [75, 0, 100, 370, 75, 370]]
```

Comment: @Vish01 if this answer helped you, please accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> t = (([75, 0], [100, 0], [100, 370]), ([75, 0], [100, 370], [75, 370])) 
>>> [tuple(sub for el in l for sub in el) for l in t]
[(75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370), (75, 0, 100, 370, 75, 370)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with this example:

```
from operator import add
from functools import reduce

reduce(add, (x for x in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

Outputs:

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Now just do this for each element in the tuple:

```
[tuple(reduce(add, x)) for x in data]
```

Outputs:

> [(75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370), (75, 0, 100, 370, 75, 370)]

Comment: Head's up: `reduce` and `add` with lists is an antipattern. Quadratic time. Although in this case it isn't very relevant

Answer (score 0):

Easy to understand version:

```
original = (([75, 0], [100, 0], [100, 370]), ([75, 0], [100, 370], [75, 370]))
final = []
for each_tuple in original:
    final_child_list = []
    for each_list in each_tuple:
        final_child_list.extend(each_list)
    final.append(final_child_list)
```

You'll get:

```
>>> final
[[75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370], [75, 0, 100, 370, 75, 370]]
# if you prefer the inside element to be tuples
>>> [tuple(x) for x in final]
[(75, 0, 100, 0, 100, 370), (75, 0, 100, 370, 75, 370)]
```

There might be shorter versions using list comprehension, but less readability.